# Riemannian metrics with vanishing curvature outside an open set

Tags: differential-geometry

Does anybody knows an example of a Riemannian metric on a manifold whose curvature(s) such as sectional, Ricci or scalar curvature is vanishing curvature outside an open set? What can be said about the structure of such Riemannian manifolds?